# What is the dual of a sum of Banach function spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, duality-theorems

Given two Banach function spaces, e.g. $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, define the sum $X=L^1+L^2$ as the class of functions $f=f_1+f_2$ having $f_i\in L^i$. Define a norm by
$$\|f\|_X=\inf\{\|f_1\|_{L^1}+\|f_2\|_{L^2}; f=f_1+f_2\} $$
where the infimum is taken over all decompositions $f=f_1+f_2$. Is there any (simple) way to see what the dual of $X$ is? As far as I can see it must be a subset of $L^\infty\cap L^2$. Could it be that this is actually the dual space?

Comment: I think that it is a general theorem that the dual to the sum is the intersection of the duals. The proof should be simple, also. Try looking in some book on functional analysis or interpolation theory if all else fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is a problem with this answer. See comment below and [the other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2322112/75808).**

From [[1](https://books.google.com/books?id=HpqF9zjZWMMC)], Chapter 3,  Exercise 6:

> If $1\leq p_0,p_1\leq \infty$, the complex spaces $L^{p_0}\cap L^{p_1}$ and $L^{p_0}+ L^{p_1}$ are rearrangement-invariant Banach functions spaces and
>   $$
>  (L^{p_s0}\cap L^{p_1})' = L^{p'_0}+ L^{p'_1};\quad
>  (L^{p_0}+ L^{p_1})' = L^{p'_0}\cap L^{p'_1}, 
> $$
>   isometrically.

In your case, this indeed implies 
$
(L^{1}+ L^{2})' =L^{\infty}\cap L^{2}.
$

---

[[1]](https://books.google.com/books?id=HpqF9zjZWMMC) Bennett, Colin, and Robert C. Sharpley. *Interpolation of operators.* Vol. 129. Academic press, 1988.

Comment: So: "the dual of $L^\infty$ is $L^1$" is in there somewhere?  Or $E'$ in this reference may not be the actual Banach space dual ...

Comment: @GEdgar Sorry, I don't understand what you mean (?)

Answer (score 5):

Sorry that I post another answer, but I cannot comment. As pointed out by GEdgar in the comments there is a problem with the above answer as the dual of $L^\infty$ is not $L^1$. In fact the authors of [1] use the notation $X'$ for the space associated to $X$, where the dual space is written as $X^*$. However the answer seems to be given in [1], Chapter 3, Exercise 3:

> Let $(X_0,X_1) $ be a conjugate couple of complex Banach spaces. Then 
>   $(X_0 \cap X_1)^* $ is isometrically isomorphic to $X_0^* +X_1^*$. 
>   (HINT: Embed $X_0\cap X_1$ as a closed subspace of the direct sum 
>   $X_0\oplus X_1$ and use the Hahn-Banach theorem).

I still have a problem with this, as this seems to require that the spaces are complex, but I don't know why. The proof seems to work without this assumption. Or is it just meant as an addition (i.e. that this works **even** for complex spaces)? In particular $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ is not complex so for a complete answer this needs to be clarified.

EDIT: Just noticed, that what I posted is exactly the wrong direction. So the actual question is answered by [1], Chapter 3, Exercise 2:

> Let $(X_0,X_1) $ be a conjugate couple of Banach spaces. Then 
>   $(X_0 + X_1)^* $ is isometrically isomorphic to $X_0^* \cap X_1^*$. 
>   (HINT: Bounded linear functionals on $X_0, X_1$ and $X_0 + X_1$ may be identified with their restrictions to $X_0 \cap X_1$).

So there complexity is not required. But I am still wondering whether complexity is actually necessary for the other statement.

[1] Bennett, Colin, and Robert C. Sharpley. Interpolation of operators. Vol. 129. Academic press, 1988.

Comment: Why would complexity be relevant? The Hahn-Banach theorem also holds for real vector spaces. Actually, the usual proof of Hahn-Banach goes through first proving it for real vector spaces, and then generalizing to complex ones.

Answer (score 1):

See also: Theorem 2.7.1 in [2] for a relatively straightforward proof of the relation for the case of spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that ($X$,$Y$) is a conjugate couple in the sense of [1] (i.e. that $X\cap Y$ is dense in both $X$ and $Y$). This is the context of [3], Chapter 3, Exercise 2 as previously discussed above.

[1] Bennett, Colin. Banach Function Spaces and Interpolation Methods. I: The abstract Theory. J Funct. Anal. 17:4, 1974. pp 409-440. doi:10.1016/0022-1236(74)90050-0

[2] Bergh, Joran and Lofstrom, Jorgen.  Interpolation Spaces, An Introduction. Springer-Verlag. 1976

[3] Bennett, Colin, and Robert C. Sharpley. Interpolation of operators. Vol. 129. Academic press, 1988.

Comment: Why certainly relevant, this is better suited as a comment.

Comment: These references are good, but I'm afraid this should be a comment instead of an answer post. If the question were explicitly asking for references (sometimes with the tag `reference request`), then this would be perfectly fine. Alternatively, you can expand this into a proper answer that is self-contained by at least outlining the solution.

Comment: I am unallowed to comment.  I am simply interested in providing a passing set of references for posterity and future readers.  Feel free to repost the above as a comment to the author (anyone who has privileges) and I will remove the post.